# Condiition disable of href in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vuetify tabs. I am not able to figureout how to disable the href in v-tabs is a condition is not meet. I have a data boolean field edit. I want to disable the href for the tabs is edit is true.
Please help me out..

```
<v-tabs v-model="tabs">
 <v-tab href="#information">INFORMATION</v-tab>
 <v-tab href="#details">DETAILS</v-tab>
 <v-tab href="#services">SERVICES</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: Is the boolean binded to all your tabs?

Comment: @JezrelDave yes.

Comment: then you should use `:disabled="edit"` in your `v-tab`

Comment: :disabled="edit" doesnt work for v-tabs

Comment: not on v-tabs but on v-tab

Comment: sorry i miss spelling I meant v-tab